# Closing Period Percentage MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

Bit of a newbie to MDX, I have been struggling with this and need help.

I have a Date Hierarchy, and I can work out the count of cases for the latest loaded quarter, but I am struggling with working out the percentage.

My query is this:

```
Member [Measures].[Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage]
As

        (
            ClosingPeriod
                    (
                        [Dates].[Quarter].[Quarter]
                        ,[Dates].[Quarter].DefaultMember
                    )
                    ,[Measures].[Count]
        )


Select 
[Measures].[Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage] On Columns
,[Things].[Category].Members On Rows
From [Stuff]
```

The output is like this:

```
        Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage
All             73
Thing1          5
Thing2          12
Thing3          (null)
Thing4          1
Thing5          32
Thing6          9
Thing7          (null)
Thing8          13
Thing9          5
Thing10         6
```

What I want to do it produce a percentage for each row, the divisor would be 73, and the output would look so:

```
    Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage
All         100%
Thing1      6.8%
Thing2      16.4%
Thing3      0%
Thing4      1.4%
Thing5      43.8%
Thing6      12.3%
Thing7      0%
Thing8      17.8%
Thing9      6.8%
Thing10     8.2%
```

I just can't figure out how to make the 73 figure static for each row so the percentage calculation can be performed.

Can anyone assist and point out where I have gone wrong?

Edit:

I imagine the solution to be along the same lines as this:

```
Member [Measures].[Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage]
As

        (
            ClosingPeriod
                    (
                    [Dates].[Quarter].[Quarter]
                    ,[Dates].[Quarter].DefaultMember
                )
                ,[Measures].[Count]
    )
/
    (
        ClosingPeriod
                (
                    [Dates].[Quarter].[Quarter]
                    ,[Dates].[Quarter].DefaultMember
                )
                ,[Measures].[Count]
    ).Parent

Select 
[Measures].[Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage] On Columns
,[Things].[Category].Members On Rows
From [Stuff]
```

This wont work, but I feel its along these lines

The key point is the calculation needs to stay the same as the members expand.

Edit Part 2:

Have figured this for the specified dimension, we are looking at:

```
Member [Measures].[Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage]
As
            (
                ClosingPeriod
                    (
                        [Dates].[Quarter].[Quarter]
                        ,[Dates].[Quarter].DefaultMember
                    )
            ,[Measures].[Distinct Count]                
            )
        /
        (
        [Complaints Category].[Category].[All]
        ,
            (
                ClosingPeriod
                    (
                        [Dates].[Quarter].[Quarter]
                        ,[Dates].[Quarter].DefaultMember
                    )
            ,[Measures].[Distinct Count]                
            )
        )
        ,Format_String = "Percent"

Select 
[Measures].[Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage] On Columns
,[Things].[Category].Members  On Rows
From [Stuff]
```

Which gives me:

```
        Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage
All             100%
Thing1          6.85%
Thing2          16.44%
Thing3          (null)
Thing4          1.37%
Thing5          43.84%
Thing6          12.33%
Thing7          (null)
Thing8          17.81%
Thing9          6.85%
Thing10         8.22%
```

Next challenge though, to get this to work across different dimensions

Any suggestions in the meantime, gladly accepted

Answer (score 0):

I may well be misunderstanding but you can just do a normal division in your caculation - either with the operator `/` or via the function `DIVIDE`:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[cnt2] 
    (
       ClosingPeriod(
           [Dates].[Quarter].[Quarter]
          ,[Dates].[Quarter].DefaultMember
       )
       ,[Measures].[Count]
       ,[Things].[Category].[All] //<< added to this tuple to reference All member
     )
MEMBER [Measures].[cnt] AS
  COUNT([Things].[Category].Members)
MEMBER [Measures].[Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage] AS
  DIVIDE(
     (
       ClosingPeriod(
           [Dates].[Quarter].[Quarter]
          ,[Dates].[Quarter].DefaultMember
       )
       ,[Measures].[Count]
     )
   , [Measures].[cnt2] //<< changed to cnt2
  ), FORMAT_STRING="##.00%"
SELECT
  [Measures].[Latest Available Full Quarter Percentage] ON COLUMNS
 ,[Things].[Category].Members ON ROWS
FROM [Stuff];
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I was looking to calculate the 73 dynamically, I just cannot figure out the syntax to do this

Comment: @toastboy the 73 is just a count of all the members in here `[Things].[Category].Members` ? If so that is easy to do dynamically - I will amend.

Comment: The 73 is the figure at the all position, which is the resultant sum of the [Things].[Category].Members